# Execute FlashForth word when pin changes

Tags: arduino, atmega, forth

I have a word that I wish to trigger on pin change:

```
: example
  ." Hello, world! "
;i
```

I am using `External Interrupt Request 1`, which is interrupt vector no. `3` according to page 65 of the datasheet and [this diagram I use](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/NicoHood/HoodLoader2/pictures/pinout.png).

```
' example 3 int!
ei
```

When I try to change the value of a pin (pin 3 in this case), nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the code I posted above, but I did get it working after looking at other examples and reading the data sheet:

```
\ Pin Change Interrupt 0
4 constant pcint0

\ Pin Change Mask Register 0
$6b constant pcmsk0

\ Pin Change Interrupt Control Register
$68 constant pcicr

ram variable example

: example+1
  1 example +!
;i

: int-enable
  ['] example+1 pcint0 int!
  ei
;

int-enable

%00000001 pcmsk0 mset
%00000111 $68 mset

\ Shorting pin 8 will now increment `example` variable.
```